# Localizing context menus in QT?

Tags: qt, localization, internationalization, cross-platform, contextmenu

What is the best way to localize default context menus in Qt?
An example is the context menu that pops up on right click from the QPlainTextEdit.
This needs to work on PC and Mac.

I know it's possible to iterate over each menu item in a custom menu, and apply translations to each item, but I'm hoping for something more automatic, ideally pulling in a os-native translated context menu.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using tr.
[tr](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/i18n-source-translation.html)

Comment: I was hoping to take advantage of native menus provided by the OS, rather than using tr on each item. - if that is possible.

Comment: I believe the menu defaults are already wrapped in tr, have you tried creating a translation file yet?